# Accessing @ConfigurationProperties from Wicket

Tags: wicket

I am using Spring Boot with Wicket and I would like to use Spring Boot's ability to read yaml application properties for configuration of my Wicket Web Application. I can get the configuration properties classes to work within Spring context, but when I use @SpringBean to inject them into a Wicket component, the bean get injected, but it is not populated with properties. What is the recommended way of accessing Spring Boot's properties from Wicket?

I am aware of this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34417457/how-to-inject-spring-properties-into-wicket-components), but the answers there talk about the use of `@Value` annotations, which does not help me.

I can autowire the configuration property bean at the application level and it is populated. I can also autowire `ApplicationContext` at the application level and then access it via the static `Application.get()`, which allows me to look up the bean using `context.getBean()`. However neither of those two solutions feels right to me.

Comment: Maybe you should show some code.

Comment: @martin-g was working on getting sample together when I discovered that my whole problem was with the debugger showing default values with `@SpringBean` injected beans, but the getters would get the correct value. I spent days banging my head and only trying to write a proper test revealed that it was a non issue all along.

Answer (score 1):

Do NOT trust the eclipse debugger when looking at `@SpringBean` injected proxies. Use getters to get the actual value.